# NSOutputStream giving -1 bytes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsoutputstream

```
NSDictionary *bundle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message,@"message", toUserName, @"receiver",fromUserName, @"sender", nil];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:bundle];           
NSOutputStream *outStream;
[toUser getInputStream:nil outputStream:&outStream];
[outStream open];
NSInteger bytes = [outStream write:[data bytes] maxLength: [data length]];
[outStream close];

success = YES;
NSLog(@"Wrote %ld bytes", bytes);
```

I'm getting: `Wrote -1 bytes`.

Comment: @anon: Dear me are you new to Objective-C?  Worse than me? :D  A NSInteger is not an object, so you can't use the object specifier in NSLog. ;)

Comment: I was wrong for other reasons but you can do what I said. But, then again `NSInteger` would have to be a pointer too in what I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `write:maxLength:` method documentation:

> **Return Value**
>   The number of bytes actually written, or -1 if an error occurs. More information about the error can be obtained with streamError. If the receiver is a fixed-length stream and has reached its capacity, 0 is returned.

The -1 return value means that an error occurred. You should use `[outStream streamError]` to get an NSError object telling you what went wrong so you can try to fix it, or to get a description of the problem for the user.